# Set bootstrap popover max width base on the page main container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to customize the Bootstrap 3 popover max width that is inside a column which you can look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hcq46Lk3/).

I wanted to make the max-width of it 40% of the container.

So, I've tried overriding the max-width of the popover container to 40%. This works if the tool-tip `#pop-over` is on `col-xs-12` container.

But if I put the `#pop-over` on a smaller container, popover container becomes smaller as well.

Is there any way to make the popover size not related to its parent container? but related to the main container? or browser width?
For example, if the popover is on the `col-xs-4` container, it should still have the same size as the popover on the `col-xs-12`

Comment: What about using `container: "body"`? https://jsfiddle.net/hcq46Lk3/1/ http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-options

Comment: did you try to set `  max-width: 40vw;` then it should get 40% of viewport widht

Comment: @Banzay I don't wanna use `vw` as much as possible because it was not supported that much on most of the browser.

Comment: @Morpheus that works like a charm!

Comment: @JF-Mechs Glad it helped you out :)